# Saxon 9B DTD locations

Tags: saxon

I'm trying to configure locate the DTDs for Saxon extensions and java types (IntelliJ editor configuration).

The namespaces:

http://saxon.sf.net 
http://saxon.sf.net/java-type

...have no DTDs available in the classpath. I've looked in the jars and everywhere and can't find an explanation or references to such DTDs on the web. I'm able to use extensions and java types, such as saxon:evaluate, successfully.

I'm using Saxon 9B.

Answer (score 0):

There are no elements or attributes in these namespaces, only functions and types. DTDs define elements and attributes. So there would be nothing for a DTD to say.

What problem are you actually trying to solve: what would you want to do with this DTD if it existed?

Comment: I understand. I was looking for tool support in IntelliJ for saxon extension functions. It asks for a DTD for this namespace, but that won't help. I'll continue looking through IntelliJ docs.

Comment: I use IntelliJ all the time for my Java work, but I never use it for XML development. It's probably improved a lot since I last tried it, but I was put off in the early days by the fact that they clearly didn't understand XML and namespaces very well. So my XML work is all in oXygen.